# What's the best way to have two themes on a single Grav CMS site?

Tags: themes, grav

I can easily switch between themes, but it rewrites the entire site, can I assign a theme to a page? In that way I can have multiple themes

Answer (score 0):

there is great plugin named `Themer` that enables you use different themes on one site individual set per page or collection

here's the github link : https://github.com/sommerregen/grav-plugin-themer

Maybe a start to your issue